# How do I use a method three times within a main method

Tags: java

I make an application where I calculate costs of a jewelry store and use a method within the main method.

This method has to be used three times with only one parameter changing. I also keep getting an error from Java saying that the method and variables are already defined,

Here this my code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class JewelleryStore
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double stateRate = 0.1;
        double luxuryRate = 0.2;
        double laborRate = 0.05;
        double extraCharge;
        int numOrdered;
        double diamondCost;
        double settingCost;
        double baseCost;
        double totalCost;
        double laborCost;
        double stateTax;
        double luxuryTax;
        double finalAmountDue;

        Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the cost of the diamond?");
        diamondCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the setting?");
        settingCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How many rings are you ordering?");
        numOrdered = keyInput.nextInt();

        baseCost = diamondCost + settingCost;
        calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
        laborCost = extraCharge;
        calcExtraCost(baseCost, stateRate);
        stateTax = extraCharge;
        calcExtraCost(baseCost, luxuryRate);
        luxuryTax = extraCharge;
        totalCost = baseCost + laborCost + stateTax + luxuryTax;
        finalAmountDue = numOrdered*totalCost;
        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jasmine Jewelry INC:  TOTAL COST  BREAKDOWN" + "\nDiamond Cost: $" +dollar.format(diamondCost) + "\nSetting Cost: $" + dollar.format(settingCost) + "\nState Tax @ 10%: $" + dollar.format(stateTax) + "\nLuxury Tax  @ 20%: $" + dollar.format(luxuryTax)+"\nLabor Charge @ 5%: $"+dollar.format(laborCost)+"\nTotal Price: $" + dollar.format(diamondCost+settingCost+stateTax+luxuryTax+laborCost) +"\n\nNumberOrdered: " + numOrdered + "\n\nAmount Due $" + dollar.format(finalAmountDue));

    }
    public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
    {
        double extraCharge = diamond*rate;
        double diamond = baseCost;
        double rate = laborCost;

    }
    public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond2, double rate2)
    {
        double extracharge = diamond2*rate2;
        double diamond = baseCost;
        double rate2 = stateTax;
    }
    public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond2, double rate3)
    {
        double extracharge = diamond1*rate3;
        double diamond2 = baseCost;
        double rate3 = luxuryTax;
    }
}
```

Comment: your code doesn't make much sense.  It sounds like you need a better fundamental understanding of Java.  I would recommend Head First Java.

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong in your code. Please try learning a bit more of the language's basics. For starters, you only need *one* method `calcExtraCost` and pass it different parameters for `rate` from the main function.

Comment: Oh dear. Reading this further, the whole question even makes less sense to me. You define variables in your functions that you never use, and your functions don't return anything either.

Comment: Help yourself by reading "Head First Core java". Many people here know answer but are not telling you because they know you won't understand it without basics.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, okay so you are new to Java.

Write a method that calcs extra cost once and call it as many times as you wish with different param, you will get passed back different results.

something like this:

```
 public static double calcExtraCost(double value, double rate)
 {
    return value*rate;
 }
```

you can add a percentage to the original value based on some rate like this:

```
baseCost = baseCost + calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
```

I recommend Head First Java as well!

Answer (score 0):

You are basically creating the same method again and again which is not needed... Just create one method the method can get different values at runtime 
**Pseudocode:**

```
public static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
 {
       // do something
return somedouble value computed
               }
```

just when calling the method you need to pass different rates as input `calcExtraCost(diamond,rate1) or calcExtraCost(diamond,rate2) or calcExtraCost(diamond,rate3 )` etc the JVM is clever enough to call the corresponding method. Plus your logic makes no sense please read the basics of java at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: And what would this method without any return type do? It defines a few variables and then discards them.

Comment: @slhck sry wanted to tell him from his example.. edited my answer..

Answer (score 0):

I think This is what u expect

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class JewelleryStore
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        double stateRate = 0.1;
        double luxuryRate = 0.2;
        double laborRate = 0.05;
        double extraCharge;
        int numOrdered;
        double diamondCost;
        double settingCost;
        double baseCost;
        double totalCost;
        double laborCost;
        double stateTax;
        double luxuryTax;
        double finalAmountDue;

        Scanner keyInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is the cost of the diamond?");
        diamondCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("What is the cost of the setting?");
        settingCost = keyInput.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("How many rings are you ordering?");
        numOrdered = keyInput.nextInt();

        baseCost = diamondCost + settingCost;
        extraCharge=calcExtraCost(baseCost, laborRate);
        laborCost = extraCharge;
        extraCharge=calcExtraCost(baseCost, stateRate);
        stateTax = extraCharge;
        extraCharge=calcExtraCost(baseCost, luxuryRate);
        luxuryTax = extraCharge;
        totalCost = baseCost + laborCost + stateTax + luxuryTax;
        finalAmountDue = numOrdered*totalCost;
        DecimalFormat dollar = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Jasmine Jewelry INC:  TOTAL COST  BREAKDOWN" + "\nDiamond Cost: $" +dollar.format(diamondCost) + "\nSetting Cost: $" + dollar.format(settingCost) + "\nState Tax @ 10%: $" + dollar.format(stateTax) + "\nLuxury Tax  @ 20%: $" + dollar.format(luxuryTax)+"\nLabor Charge @ 5%: $"+dollar.format(laborCost)+"\nTotal Price: $" + dollar.format(diamondCost+settingCost+stateTax+luxuryTax+laborCost) +"\n\nNumberOrdered: " + numOrdered + "\n\nAmount Due $" + dollar.format(finalAmountDue));

    }
    static double calcExtraCost(double diamond, double rate)
    {
        double extraCharge = diamond*rate;
        return extraCharge;

    }
}
```